# What is the difference between '.scroll' and 'silentScroll'?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Just for my own knowledge, what is the real difference between jQuery `.scroll` and jQuery Mobile `.silentScroll`? I've read that `silentScroll` is used to scroll without triggering the scroll event, but what does really mean? And to add to that, why is `silentScroll` presumably better for mobile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.silentScroll` is used to scroll without triggering the scroll event, meaning you won't bind a function to run with `silentScroll`, instead you can scroll to a certain location in the page by clicking on a button or through any other action. With that said, when using `.silentScroll`, nothing will happen when you scroll on the page, unless an action explicitly triggers the scroll (i.e. button click).

Since `silentScroll` doesn't use an event listener, it's better for mobile because it's faster when the scroll is triggered by a certain action, as opposed to having an event listening to the scroll all the time.

Answer (score 1):

.scroll() either attach a function to be executed when the element is scrolled(scroll event is thrown) -e.g

```
 $("div").scroll(function(){
   $("span").text( count+= 1);
 });
```

or triggers the scroll event on the specified element - e.g

```
 $("button").click(function(){
        $("div").scroll();
    });
```

.silentScroll() has nothting to deal with events but just scroll the element to the specified Y(vertical) position.